# Системные переменные кодировки MySQL

Tags: переменные, mysql

существует 3 системные переменные кодировок:

1. `character_set_connection`
2. `character_set_client`
3. `character_set_result`

Они отвечают за представление байтов в виде символов. На этапе когда клиент шлет данные, когда данные пришли и когда данные посылаются обратно.
Но зачем так усложнять все, почему нельзя установить всего 1 кодировку, согласно которой SQL сервер будет управляться с данным у себя внутри(например при группировке)?
Ведь если клиент прислал серверу , скажем, 30 байт данных(которые соответствуют utf8), то серверу достаточно знать 1 кодировку!

PS Почему в бд нельзя поставить и encoding? Она же может быть разной для разных кодировок

Comment: непонятно что вас удивляет, кодировка базы данных и даже отдельных таблиц тоже может быть выставлена.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что задача сервера БД - обеспечить не только хранение данных и надежность, но и максимальную гибкость работы.

**Обновление**

Клиент может иметь какие-то ограничения по передаче и получению данных, поэтому БД может выполнять часть работы за него. Это и есть гибкость - БД может работать с разными клиентами по-разному и спокойно относиться к различным кодировкам приема, хранения и выдачи результатов, фактически снимая большинство "кодировочных" проблем при работе.

Comment: @Fike про какую гибкость вы говорите, простите за глупый вопрос

Comment: @eicto меня удивляет тот факт, что поставь я на сервере кодировку cp1251(все 3 кодировки Mysql server) и отправив ему кириллицу в utf8, он мне попортит все отправленные данные. Зачем и самое главное **как** он это делает.